# Integration by parts using functions in $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $\Omega$ be an open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\{u_n\} \subset C_c^1(\Omega)$ be so that both $u_n$ and $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_j}$ are Cauchy in $L^2(\Omega)$. If $u,v$ are $L^2$ limits of $u_n$ and $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_j}$ respectively and $\phi \in C_c^1(\Omega)$ then $\int_\Omega u \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_j} \, dx = - \int_\Omega v \phi \, dx$.

My attempt: Let ${n_k}$ be a subsequence so that $u_{n_k} \to u$ a.e in $\Omega$ and $\frac{\partial u_{n_k}}{\partial x_j} \to v$ a.e in $\Omega$ by integration by parts
$$\int_\Omega u_{n_k} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_j} = - \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u_{n_k}}{\partial x_j} \phi \, dx$$
for each $k$. However, I am not sure how to bound the above sequence of functions to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: One small comment: The integration by parts formula is only true if $\Omega$ has some sort of regular boundary, e.g. Lipschitz boundary. Even though I can't come up with a counterexample at the top of my head, otherwise, it's probably false.

Comment: @Meowdog would the statement still holds true if $\Omega$ does not have regular boundary? such that I can assume integration by parts?

Comment: Depends on your region, I don't know what your plans are. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358606/on-which-regions-can-greens-theorem-not-be-applied?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be interesting to you, but it is hard to even define the integral $\int_{\partial \Omega}$ if the boundary is not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue dominated convergence thm. might not be appropriate here. Here is no need to pass to a subsequence. Instead, we use Hölder inequality:
$$
\left \lvert \int_{\Omega} u_n \partial_{x_j}\phi~\mathrm{d}x -\int_{\Omega} u \partial_{x_j}\phi~\mathrm{d}x\right \rvert \leq \int_{\Omega} \lvert \partial_{x_j} \phi \rvert \lvert u_n - u \rvert~\mathrm{d}x \overset{\text{Hölder}}{\leq} \lVert \partial_{x_j} \phi \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \lVert u_n - u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
Note carefully here that $\lVert \partial_{x_j} \phi \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ is finite, since $\phi$ is conitnuous and has compact support. The other limit works exactly the same way.

$u$ lives in the so called sobolev space $H^1_0(\Omega) := \overline{C^1_c(\Omega)}^{\lVert \cdot \rVert}$ where $\lVert u \rVert := \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \sum_{j=1}^d \lVert \partial_{x_j} u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$. These are very interesting and you should read about them, if you want to better understand what is happening here.